# prometheus rule: check for expression value in range

Tags: prometheus

In a prometheus alert rule, how do I check for a value to be in a certain range?

```
for eg., (x > 80 && x <= 100);
```

when x is a complex expression it feels unnecessary to evaluate it twice. is there another way to represent this expression?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do `x < 100 > 80` to chain them.

Comment: I guess you meant, x > 80 < 100. This seems to work, although the expression is uncommon, I was expecting a function for this requirement.  but this is great. Thanks.

Comment: or 80 < x < 100

Comment: How do you do this when the range is exclusive? I mean when X should be outside of a range. i.e: X < 80 or X > 100